# Created System Column Blank In API Call

Tags: smartsheet-api, smartsheet-api-2.0

I am making REST calls against the Reports API endpoint, and pulling that data into a separate application.  I am able to pull all of the report columns with its data, with the exception of the Created (System Column), which always returns nothing/null.

To rule out the application being the issue, I used the built in Smartsheet connector in Power BI and am getting the same blank results there.

Are there any known limitation about pulling date system columns out of the API?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you discovered a bug in the Smartsheet API! Thanks for drawing attention to this. I've submitted a bug report to the dev team at Smartsheet.

Apologies for the inconvenience. What are you trying to accomplish with your application? I might be able to help you come up with a work-around.

Comment: Thank you for getting back to me about the bug. 

Currently I am pulling the data into Cisco Information Server, where I am combining it with some other data sources.

Comment: I know it's a tough ask, but is there any kind of estimate of when the bug will be addressed?

Comment: Let me see what I can find out. How about you email devrel@smartsheet.com and we can continue the conversation there.